# unfortunately app has stopped working- android emulator

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-emulator

I am new to android app development. While learning app development I was stuck on the error:

> UNFORTUNATELY APP HAS STOPPED WORKING

My app opens properly but when i enter the text right and click on button it stopped working and shows the above error.}

**TextPlay.java**:

```
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class TextPlay extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.text);
        Button ChkCmd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bResults);
        final ToggleButton passTog = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tbPassword);
        final EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCommands);
        final TextView display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
        passTog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (passTog.isChecked()) {
                    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
                            | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
                } else {
                    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                }

            }

        });
        ChkCmd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String check = input.getText().toString();
                if (check.contentEquals("left")) {
                    display.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                } else if (check.contentEquals("right")) {
                    display.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                } else if (check.contentEquals("center")) {
                    display.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                } else if (check.contentEquals("blue")) {

                }

            }
        });

    }

}
```

This is my  **MainFest:**

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            package="com.example.dikshant"
            android:versionCode="1"
            android:versionName="1.0" >

            <uses-sdk
                android:minSdkVersion="8"
                android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

            <application
                android:allowBackup="true"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
                <activity
                    android:name=".Splash"
                    android:label="@string/app_name" >
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>
                <activity
                    android:name=".MainActivity"
                    android:label="@string/app_name" >
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="com.example.dikshant.MAINACTIVITY" />

                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>
                 <activity
                    android:name=".Menu"
                    android:label="@string/app_name" >
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="com.example.dikshant.MENU" />

                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>
                    <activity
                    android:name=".TextPlay"
                    android:label="@string/app_name" >
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="com.example.dikshant.TEXTPLAY" />
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>
            </application>

        </manifest>

    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is my **text.xml** file

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/background2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/etCommands" 
                android:hint="Type a command" 
                android:password="true" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:weightSum="100"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Button
                android:layout_weight="20"
                android:id="@+id/bResults"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Try Command" />
        enter code here
            <ToggleButton
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:checked="true"
                android:layout_weight="80"
                android:id="@+id/tbPassword"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ToggleButton" />
        </LinearLayout>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvResults"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Invalid"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

**LOGCAT**

```
07-16 21:08:06.996: D/dalvikvm(1906): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 49K, 4% free 3035K/3160K, paused 58ms, total 60ms
07-16 21:08:07.036: I/dalvikvm-heap(1906): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.808MB for 2915856-byte allocation
07-16 21:08:07.096: D/dalvikvm(1906): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 3% free 5880K/6008K, paused 57ms, total 57ms
07-16 21:08:07.786: D/(1906): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8bcac50, tid 1906
07-16 21:08:07.846: W/EGL_emulation(1906): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-16 21:08:07.856: D/OpenGLRenderer(1906): Enabling debug mode 0
07-16 21:09:00.396: D/AndroidRuntime(1906): Shutting down VM
07-16 21:09:00.396: W/dalvikvm(1906): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1ac2ba8)
```

--->>RED Highlighted Error from now:

```
07-16 21:09:00.576: E/AndroidRuntime(1906): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-16 21:09:00.576: E/AndroidRuntime(1906): Process: com.example.dikshant, PID: 1906
07-16 21:09:00.576: E/AndroidRuntime(1906): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-16 21:09:00.576: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at com.example.dikshant.TextPlay$2.onClick(TextPlay.java:51)
07-16 21:09:00.576: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
07-16 21:09:00.576: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
07-16 21:09:00.576: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-16 21:09:00.576: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-16 21:09:00.576: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-16 21:09:00.576: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-16 21:09:00.576: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-16 21:09:00.576: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-16 21:09:00.576: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-16 21:09:00.576: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-16 21:09:00.576: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Show you StackTrace, please. What error are you getting? In which line?

Comment: **Red Highlighted error in LOGCAT** 07-16 21:09:00.396: W/dalvikvm(1906): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1ac2ba8)
07-16 21:09:00.576: E/AndroidRuntime(1906): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-16 21:09:00.576: E/AndroidRuntime(1906): Process: com.example.dikshant, PID: 1906
07-16 21:09:00.576: E/AndroidRuntime(1906): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-16 21:09:00.576: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):  at com.example.dikshant.TextPlay$2.onClick(TextPlay.java:51)
07-16 21:09:00.576: E/AndroidRuntime(1906):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)

Comment: Edit your Question with the Full StackTrace, instead of a comment, please.

Comment: It is in your TextPlay.java line 51 that your app is crashing? What is that line?

Comment: yes its in TextPlay.java i think
nd code-- > String check=input.getText().toString();
     if(check.contentEquals("left")){
      display.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
     }else if(check.contentEquals("right")){
      display.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
     }else if(check.contentEquals("center")){
      display.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
     }else if(check.contentEquals("blue")){
      
     }

Comment: actually i m entering the text "center" and clicking on button.... then it is crashing! line 51... is elseif code for gravity.Center

Comment: Why has your TextView id R.id.tvDisplay? Shouldn't it be R.id.tvResults?

Comment: Exactly!.. that was my silly Error anyway thank U :)

Comment: You are welcome. Feel free to delete your question if it is solved. Otherwise I can write an answer so you can accept it as right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you are associating the wrong id to your `TextView`.

```
 final TextView display=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
```

It should be `R.id.tvResults` instead, like you have defined in your layout.

Just change it and your code will run ok :D